# How does redux and immutable data structures handle large data sets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, immutable.js

I am building an app where I constantly have to do queries that return unique data sets that can range from 5,000 - 50,000 csv elements. It seems rather inefficient to keep all these queries in memory. The data sets are used for data visualization. Does anyone have suggestions in how to approach this? Or should I just ditch redux / immutable.js?

Comment: are you actually running low on ram, or is this a solution in search of a problem?

Comment: I haven't implemented it, but I just want to get some opinions before I actually go ahead and do so. The initial idea did not include such large data sets so I decided to go ahead and decided to go with this front end stack.

Comment: well, i'm all for ditching un-needed frameworks, but i don't see how that applies to the over-all loading and purging strategy your application needs, which will be the case no matter what you're using...

Comment: If you aren't planning to work with and change the data at any point and just use it to feed a visualisation then i don't see any point in using immutable.js. For any kind of webGL visualisations, use Javascripts [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) - even if doing DOM or canvas it might be a good thing to store your data in.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested immutable with a large `JSON` file (`22mb`) and you're correct it was **very** inefficient. The particular pain point was internet explorer; reducing and filtering that set of data took almost `30s`. I don't consider this a fault of Immutable.js however, it's goal isn't to process 250,000 items of JSON in one nuclear data explosion (which is what I was testing in this case, to find the limits of the browsers computational limits with regards to filtering in particular). But it's important to note it's not a library that's designed primarily for speed.

Native objects however brought that time down to at most `6s` on IE12 (ironic that 11 was faster, but their you go). But the avg was between `1-2s`.

So in short, I wouldn't use immutable for large data sets, I would use native objects and then perhaps use Immutable for a subset of that large dataset if you have a particular design reason for this.